# Custom model in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on, rails-admin

I have such problem:

I'm using rails_admin and gem acts_as_taggable_on.
Second have model ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag. And I need to manage it in admin part.
Google and StackOverflow don't know answer, or I forgot, how to google =(

So, what I tried:
Added that in initializers/rails_admin.rb

```
config.model ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag do
  label 'Тэг'
  label_plural 'Тэги'
  configure :name, :string
end
```

Still no reaction. But if I try to add `config.included_models = [ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag]`
Then I see that model in admin, but this is whitelist, so I see there only tags, no other model =)

Tried to

```
config.included_models = :all
```

and

```
config.included_models << ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag
```

Still nothing =(

I would be very grateful if anybody can help me.

P.S. Nowtime see only one way - add empty class ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag in app/models
But I think, that is not good way.

Comment: Maybe not exactly duplicates but this question may be relevant.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077900/how-add-tag-model-actsastaggableon-in-rails-admin

Answer (score 2):

You need to add them all if you go Whitelist mode:

```
config.included_models = ['ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag', <all other models>]
```

You can run `rake rails_admin:install`to have the list of all the models that RailsAdmin has detected in `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb.example`

Comment: Unless you find out why ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag isn't found, I can't see any other solution.

Comment: I know why it doesn't found. RailsAdmin requiring only app/models directory.

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you the ability to list, filter, edit, search tags and see how many times they are used.  This example does not give one the ability to change the item using a tag or its association to said tag.

Create the file:
    app/models/tag.rb

Define the contents as:

```
class Tag < ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag
  attr_accessible :name, :as => :admin
end
```