# how add tag model (ActsAsTaggableOn) in rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-admin, acts-as-taggable-on, kaminari

I install rails admin and include all model in active record in rails admin,

first time, when install rails admin display me this error

```
NoMethodError in RailsAdmin::MainController#index

undefined method `per_page_kaminari' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000006713e18>
```

and fixed it by added this configure

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
    config.page_method_name = :per_page_kaminari
end
```

when install acts_as_taggable_on gem in project, rails admin did't add tag model in it ( i added field tags_list in other model), but i want to add tag model in rails admin to manage tags (index,create,edit and destroy)..

I added this line

```
config.included_models = ['ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag']
```

in rails_admin.rb and it display me tag model in dashboard, but when open list tags, it display me again this error

```
NoMethodError in RailsAdmin::MainController#index

undefined method `per_page_kaminari' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000006713e18>
```

what should i do to add tag model in rails admin and manage tags ?!

Comment: This may not be a duplicate but I believe my answer to the question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424293/custom-model-in-rails-admin/28331228#28331228 will solve this question as well.

Answer (score 4):

I had to solve the same issue here. 
I used the [gem 'rails_admin_tag_list'](https://github.com/kryzhovnik/rails_admin_tag_list) but latest version from rubygem is not updated for rails 4 (doesnt support RailsAdmin Property).
So you need to get the one from master that include the [fix](https://github.com/kryzhovnik/rails_admin_tag_list/commit/a9a4e31af6fdd2124110d0dff81ab97950803e65).

```
gem 'rails_admin_tag_list', git: 'https://github.com/kryzhovnik/rails_admin_tag_list.git', branch: 'master'
```

Indeed add:

```
config.included_models = ['YourModel', 'ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag']
```

and

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable # dont add attr_accessible stuff since we're in rails 4
end
```

then choose the config for tag list:

```
config.model 'YourModel' do
  configure :tag_list  do
    partial 'tag_list_with_autocomplete'
  end
  exclude_fields :body, :locale, :base_tags, :tags
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The exact same issue occurs with ActiveAdmin: [Manage acts_as_taggable tags with activeadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698242/manage-acts-as-taggable-tags-with-activeadmin). I solved it with the same solution:

Add an initializer to `config/initializers` with the custom Kaminari code:

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
    config.page_method_name = :per_page_kaminari
end
```

Create a new class in `app/models` called `tag.rb`:

```
# This class fixes a bug between Kaminari, RailsAdmin, and ActsAsTaggableOn.
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Use the `Tag` model instead of `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag` in RailsAdmin config:

```
config.included_models = [Tag]
```

Comment: I am new in ruby and rails so i am still understading the data flow and architecture. My question is how rails_addmin (and ActiveAdmin too) was able to grab the information from the `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag` model?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution with rails 4 and fields configuration (must be before the `congig.included_models` call):

```
config.model ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag do 
    edit do 
      exclude_fields :taggings_count
      exclude_fields :taggings
    end
  end

  config.model ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging do 
    edit do 
      exclude_fields :context
    end
  end

  admin_models = ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.map(&:name)
  admin_models.delete("PgSearch::Document") #if you use it
  admin_models.delete("PaperTrail::Version") #if you use it
  #add other models to exclude here
  config.included_models = admin_models
```